# How to query from a converted date column using AS keyword

Tags: select, presto

This one giving me error `Column 'new_date' cannot be resolved`

```
    SELECT from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10)) AS new_date 
    FROM "db_name"."table_name" 
    WHERE new_date > from_iso8601('2018-08-26') limit 10;
```

This has also gave me the same error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10)) FROM "db_name"."table_name") AS new_date
WHERE new_date > from_iso8601('2018-08-26') limit 10;
```

Comment: SQL wont let you do this. You can make it as query in query.

Comment: @programerAnel Check my edits. same error with nesting query too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out this as

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10)) as day,*
  FROM "db"."table"
 )
WHERE  day > date_parse('2018-08-26', '%Y-%m-%d')  
 limit 10
```

Comment: That was something like i would approach and was talking about.